# Content under fixed header when anchor link is clicked on

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to make my sections sit below the fixed header. I have it to where when the webpage loads, the container is sitting right below the header, but if I click on the header logo to go to the first section `(#splash-screen)` of the webpage, then it doesn't sit below the header anymore. There's 10-30px of the splash screen under the header when the header logo is clicked on.

[Link to code](https://codepen.io/chataolauj/pen/QzJRLr?editors=1100)

**EDIT:** The issue isn't with the first (#splash-screen) section only; it's with all sections (4 total). Some amount of px of each section gets hidden under the fixed header when their corresponding anchor link is clicked on. It's not noticeable for the other 3 sections because there is a lot of whitespace, but I want a fix for all sections because I'm going to add more content to each section, which may or may not fill up the whole section.

Comment: Just change `<a href="#splash-screen">` to `<a href="#">` to navigate to the top of the page.

Comment: @Terry That only fixes the issue for the #splash-screen section. I made an edit to my post to clarify what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `<div id="empty-space"></div>` and add `#splash-screen video {top: 50px;}` css in your code. This will fix your problem.

Comment: That only fixes the issue for the #splash-screen section. I made an edit to my post to clarify what I need help with.